# Changing current ajax lookup query dynamically from select box in Ember.js

Tags: javascript, ajax, ember.js

I am building a data reporting application in Ember.js and I have two select boxes (both components) which choose the date range (only by month) for the currently displayed data.

What should happen is when either `select` box is changed, the server gets hit with another request and all the data gets reloaded from the given period.  But I can't work out how to get the Route's `model` method to rerun - I guess effectively observe the `change` event on the `select`s?

I have tried doing something like this:

```
Dashboard.MonthlyReviewRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    query: {},
    model: function( params ) {
        console.log(params);
        var args = { page: 'monthly_review' };
        args = Ember.merge(args, {});
        return this.store.find('report', args);
    },
    setupController: function(controller, model) {
        controller.set('model', model);
        controller.set('report', model.get('content')[0]);
    }
});
```

and then

```
Dashboard.SelectComponent = Ember.Component.extend({
    tagName: 'select',
    change: function(e) {
        Dashboard.MonthlyReviewRoute.query.value = 5;
    }
}
```

But how do I get the model to reload?!

Still getting my head around this event driven stuff so any help greatly appreciated and please excuse me if I'm not getting something really basic..!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

transition to the route and send the id/filters to it.

from your component, you should send an action, change, with the necessary information.  From your controller/route they should have an action that will handle the sent action.  They can then do a transitionToRoute/transitionTo and send in the route and the id/filters to use for the route.

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/utuhAKo/1/edit

Comment: Here's a simple example of it.

Comment: Amazing. Transitioning to the route is the bit I was missing - thanks again